# Rails CSV import failing with optional columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm importing a csv file with product info into a rails 4 app. I have four image fields in the csv. If some products have less than 4 images, the file doesn't load.

Here is my import code in the model:

```
def self.import(file, userid)

    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

      listing_hash = {:name => row['Name'], :description => row['Description'], 
      :price => row['Price'], :category => row['Category'], :inventory => row['Inventory'],
      :image => URI.parse(row['Image']), :image2 => URI.parse(row['Image2']),
      :image3 => URI.parse(row['Image3']), :image4 => URI.parse(row['Image4']),
      :userid => userid}

      listing = Listing.where(name: listing_hash["name"]) 

      if listing.count == 1 
        listing.first.update_attributes(listing_hash)
      else
        Listing.create!(listing_hash)
       end # end if !product.nil?
    end # end CSV.foreach
end # end self.import(file)
```

My validates statement in the model doesn't require even a single image.

```
validates :name, :description, :price, :inventory, :category, presence: true
```

How do I fix it so that the csv imports even if a product doesn't have all 4 images?

Comment: Are you getting an exception? It could be that you are attempting to call `URI.parse` and passing in `nil`. You may have to check for the value first.

Comment: I'm not getting any rails error. I just get a flash notice saying invalid csv file format. but you're right, it looks like i am passing a nil value. How do I tell rails to check if there is a value? I've seen code like `if image3.blank?` but I'm not sure how to add this in the above code.

Comment: It depends on your business needs and how you handle nil image values. You could add a method and check if the key exists. The easiest way would be to use `#fetch` which allows you to specify a default value in the event the key doesn't exist. Be careful though because if you don't provide a default value in the event of a missing key it `raises` an exception. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch

Comment: I don't want a default value. I want it to check if there is a value before trying to import a the null field. How do I do that within the method above. Sounds like I need some type of an if command but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

```
listing_hash = {:name => row['Name'], :description => row['Description'], 
  :price => row['Price'], :category => row['Category'], :inventory => row['Inventory'],
  :userid => userid}.tap do |list_hash|
    list_hash[:image] = URI.parse(row['Image']) if row['Image']
    list_hash[:image2] = URI.parse(row['Image2']) if row['Image2'] #repeat for each image
  end

  listing = Listing.where(name: listing_hash["name"]) 

  if listing.count == 1 
    listing.first.update_attributes(listing_hash)
  else
    Listing.create!(listing_hash)
   end # end if !product.nil?
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.